# What is the difference between HTTP API and REST API resource types in design center?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform, mule-connector

I having been trying to find the difference between HTTP API and REST API resource types but not getting the clear difference. When and how should one use HTTP API ? A use case would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A "REST API" (Representational state transfer) is an API that follows a certain architectural style, based on HTTP verbs (get, post, etc.). A REST API is always HTTP based.

An "HTTP API" simply only says that the HTTP protocol is used. A HTTP API doesn't necessarily have to be a REST API if it doesn't follow REST architectural styles.

You could say that a HTTP API could be any interface that you connect to over HTTP whereas REST API is only a subset of that group, that adheres to stricter rules.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange (not necessarily in Design Center), the REST APIs refer to APIs that are defined (using RAML or OAS) and implemented with MuleSoft tools (AnypointStudio) and published to Exchange, where as HTTP APIs refers to RESTful APIs that are created using other 3rd party tools whose HTTP/S URLs can be registered as assets within Exchange.  HTTP APIs can also refer to a temporary placeholder created by a private Exchange user for future management of that endpoint (via API Manager).